# Rename files in install part of homebrew formula

Tags: homebrew

I'm writing a homebrew formula, that installs a alternate clang version. As I want 
both, the original, system-provided `clang` and the modified clang in my PATH, I would like to rename the modified one to `clang-omp`.

One attempt is to do this in the install-part of the formula. Sadly without success.

```
def install
  #...
  system "./configure", "--prefix=#{prefix}"
  system "make", "install"

  # The following isn't working:
  (bin/'clang').mv 'clang-omp'
  (bin/'clang++').mv 'clang++-omp'
end
```

Another idea was to mark the formula as `keg-only`, and create install the binaries manually while changing the names.

Yet another approach (maybe the best) might be to configure the symlinks created in `/usr/local/bin/*`. But I can't find any information on the symlink creation step.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `install`: `mv bin/"clang", bin/"clang-omp"`

Grepping through the installed formulas in e.g. /usr/local/Library/Formula can give you a good sense of what works.

Comment: That formula path might be `/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula` now.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this paragraph of the Homebrew formula cookbook documentation](https://docs.brew.sh/Formula-Cookbook#bininstall-foo), one could rename a package by using the `=>` notation, e.g.:

```
def install
  bin.install "n3dr-macos-10.15" => "n3dr"
end
```